# Insert data in mongodb using javascript loop

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I want to insert data in a mongodb collection with a javascript loop.
Here is my code :

```
var collection = db.DATA.find();

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        db.PARSED_DATA.insert(collection[i].folders);
}
```

I have the error :

> 2017-08-04T10:17:06.390+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] TypeError: collection[i] is undefined :
>   @(shell):2:9

When i execute in mongodb shell the commands :

```
var collection = db.DATA.find();
db.PARSED_DATA.insert(collection[0].folders);
db.PARSED_DATA.insert(collection[1].folders);
db.PARSED_DATA.insert(collection[2].folders);
```

I have the expected result and i still don't uderstand why my for loop doesn't work.

EDIT :
When i execute this inside Robo 3T i get the expected result :

```
var collection = db.DATA.find().toArray();

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        db.PARSED_DATA.insert(collection[i].folders);
}
```

[Result in Robo 3T](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7s3vM.png)

But when i execute it inside my bash code with

```
mongo <myip>:27017 < db_parse.js
```

I get the error again

Comment: are you sure that **your index isn't out of range**? You might have `collection.length === 1` but still your loop goes up to `3`. Change with: `for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++)`

Comment: Look, what is stored in your collection, before your loop: console.dir(collection);

Comment: I add the data in my previous post. I will try your solution.

Comment: `var collection = db.DATA.find();` is a **cursor** and not an array. Use `var collection = db.DATA.find().toArray()` when you want an array.

Comment: @NeilLunn : Thanks a lot that solved my problem !

Comment: @NeilLunn i still have problems when i execute it into my shell. I will edit the orginal post.

Comment: Well you are not really doing it correctly, period. You really should be "iterating a cursor" as a general practice, and that can be done with `.forEach()` instead. And if the data actually is small enough then you can simply take the `.toArray()` result and [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) into [`.insertMany()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/) in one request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieve to create what i expect with these codes :

**db_parse.sh**

```
mongo <myip>:27017 < db_parse.js
```

**db_parse.js**

```
use <db_name>

var collection = db.DATA.find();

while(collection.hasNext()){
        db.PARSED_DATA.insert(collection.next().folders);
}
```

I use [this](http://Iterate%20a%20Cursor%20in%20the%20mongo%20Shell) MongoDB manual.